# How to call event jQuery-File-Upload in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blueimp

I want to check from api first before upload file

```
$('.file_upload_button_wrapper').live('click', function () {
        // check here
        $.ajax({
            url: '/?app=files&getfile=ajax%2Fupload.php',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                //$('.result').html(data);

                if (data.data.message =="DAT"){

                    $.confirm({
                        'title'     : 'Lỗi',
                        'message'   : 'Tài khoản đã hết hạn sử dụng. <br />Bạn có muốn gia hạn để tiếp tục upload ?',
                        'buttons'   : {
                            'Yes'   : {
                                'class' : 'blue',
                                'action': function(){
                                    window.location="http://id.kgp.vn";

                                }
                            },
                            'No'    : {
                                'class' : 'gray',
                                'action': function(){}  // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
                            }
                        }

                    });

                }

                else{

                    $('.file_upload_start').trigger('click');
                }

            }

        });
 // $('.file_upload_start').trigger('click');
return false;
    });
```

and I have function to open file and upload.

```
$(function () {
        $('.file_upload_start').fileupload({
            dropZone:$('#content'), // restrict dropZone to content div
            add:function (e, data) {
                var files = data.files;
                var totalSize = 0;

                if (files) {
```

....

I have problem when call this function in ajax when it succeeds because ajax check first and after that upload file.

`if I call  $('.file_upload_start').trigger('click');` in success ajax it don't work but I call in

`$('.file_upload_button_wrapper').live('click', function () { }`

It works.

How to call this event in ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I had solve this problem by assign `async:False` in ajax and it work well.